# Is there a way to get yourself to show up on a map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft on PC and when I tried to use a map I didn't appear on it. I went into creative and still couldn't get myself to appear on a map. Is there a type of map I need to use or have they removed that feature?

Comment: Are you in the area? If you're really far away, your dot disappears. Or maybe it was just not very visible because of similarly coloured stuff around it?

Comment: I am in the area. The entire map just auto completes and I'm not there

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Can you reproduce it reliably, for example in a copy of the world? And can you make a screen recording?

Comment: I'll try and see if it keeps happening. Only really tried on that server and assumed it was an update or I was just being dumb.

Comment: Is this about the bedrock edition? The [minecraft] tag is for the Java edition exclusively.

Comment: Yes it is Java.

Comment: The accepted answer only works for the bedrock edition (and maybe console, too, but definitely not in the java edition), how did you craft the map?

Comment: I got it straight from the Creative menu, it was the only one that would show up. I don't know if it was just a glitch or if it was just me but I went on a new server and found the right map.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to "enhance" your map with a Compass

to do that, there are two ways. either;

put the items in an anvil like this:
`Map + Compass = Map that has location ON`

or put the items in the new Chartography table In the same way:
`Map + Compass = Map that has location ON`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem for me was that I was using an outdated resource pack. My indicator showed up on the map right after I removed the resource pack.

Answer (score -4):

You need to create a map with compass. Put compass in the middle and paper around it.

Comment: The asker is obviously already using a map.

Comment: The bedrock edition has 2 types of maps: locator maps, which are crafted with a compass in the middle and shows player positions, and a regular map, which is crafted with 9 paper and does not show player positions. The question is about the java edition though (according to the tag), there is only one type of map in the java edition and it is the one that you craft with a compass in the middle.